# Update table on multi inner join

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do the following update:

```
UPDATE tbl_claim

INNER JOIN tbl_mbr ON tbl_mbr.MBR_NUM = tbl_mbr_cov.MBR_NUM
INNER JOIN tbl_claim ON tbl_claim.MBR_ID = tbl_mbr.MBR_ID

SET tbl_claim.Mbr_Cov_Id = tbl_mbr_cov.MBR_COV_ID
```

But I get an:

```
[Err] 1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'tbl_claim'
```

Then I tried this:

```
UPDATE tbl_claim AS A

INNER JOIN tbl_mbr AS C ON C.MBR_NUM = tbl_mbr_cov.MBR_NUM AS D
INNER JOIN tbl_claim AS B ON B.MBR_ID = C.MBR_ID

SET A.Mbr_Cov_Id = D.MBR_COV_ID
```

Which gives me another error:

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'as D INNER JOIN tbl_claim AS B ON B.MBR_ID = C.MBR_ID
```

But I don't know how to assign the alias for tbl_mbr_cov?

What is the correct solution?

Edit:

There are 3 tables and the relevant fields are:

```
tbl_claim:
CLAIM_ID (PK)
MBR_ID
Mbr_Cov_Id

tbl_mbr:
MBR_ID (PK)
MBR_NUM

tbl_mbr_cov:
MBR_COV_ID (PK)
MBR_NUM
```

Linking field names are identical in the 3 tables as indicated above.
We would like to update tbl_claim.Mbr_Cov_Id to equal the value in tbl_mbr_cov.MBR_COV_ID

This query works okay, so I know the join makes sense:

```
SELECT
tbl_claim.CLAIM_ID,
tbl_claim.MBR_ID,
tbl_claim.Mbr_Cov_Id,
tbl_mbr.MBR_ID,
tbl_mbr.MBR_NUM,
tbl_mbr_cov.MBR_COV_ID,
tbl_mbr_cov.MBR_NUM
FROM
tbl_mbr_cov
INNER JOIN tbl_mbr ON tbl_mbr.MBR_NUM = tbl_mbr_cov.MBR_NUM
INNER JOIN tbl_claim ON tbl_claim.MBR_ID = tbl_mbr.MBR_ID
```

It seems to me, if you can run this query, there must be a simple way to update the tbl_claim.Mbr_Cov_Id field.

Comment: You are referring `tbl_mbr_cov` in the joining condition but you have never joined the table

Comment: try to remove `as D`  :-) ;-)

Comment: I've just reread your query twice and @AbhikChakraborty comment. So I removed my answer. your query has absolutly no sense. show us all your 4 tables structure and relations, logic and conditions you want to apply. and then we can go somewhere

Comment: While the update does not work, a query based upon that join works just  fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this statement:

```
UPDATE tbl_claim

SET Mbr_Cov_Id = tbl_mbr_cov.MBR_COV_ID

FROM tbl_claim AS A
INNER JOIN tbl_mbr_cov ON A.[your_field] = tbl_mbr_cov.[your_field]
INNER JOIN tbl_mbr ON tbl_mbr.MBR_NUM = tbl_mbr_cov.MBR_NUM
INNER JOIN tbl_claim ON tbl_claim.MBR_ID = tbl_mbr.MBR_ID

WHERE [your_primary_key] = A.[your_primary_key]
```

Comment: I don't see how to make that work. There is no common key between A (tbl_claim) and tbl_mbr_cov.

Comment: oh.. That's a problem in this case.. How could you set a value if you not have a Key between two tables

Comment: Yes, that's is what i am trying to solve. It seems to me if I can successfully join the tables (I can) then I should be able to pass a value from one to the other - yes?

Comment: @AlphaBase as I wrote in comments, you should **show us all your 4 tables structure and relations** if you still need help

Comment: This query works: SELECT
tbl_claim.CLAIM_ID,
tbl_claim.MBR_ID,
tbl_mbr.MBR_ID,
tbl_mbr.MBR_NUM,
tbl_mbr_cov.MBR_NUM
FROM
tbl_mbr_cov
INNER JOIN tbl_mbr ON tbl_mbr.MBR_NUM = tbl_mbr_cov.MBR_NUM
INNER JOIN tbl_claim ON tbl_claim.MBR_ID = tbl_mbr.MBR_ID

Comment: Alex, I updated my original question with the info from the 3 tables. Hope that helps. Thanks